# Terraform doesn't delete auto-scaling group with scale-in protection enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform is failing to destroy the auto-scaling group when scale in protection in turned on, is there any workaround for this?

Tried using this but under activity section of auto-scaling groups in AWS console I saw it was cancelled because scale-in protection is enabled.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name ${self.name} --min-size 0 --desired-capacity 0"

  }
```

Comment: Are you using termination lifecycle hooks on the instances?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, I'm not aware about this. This ASG was is for capacity provider of my ECS deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`force_delete` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#force_delete) on the `aws_autoscaling_group` resource to delete the ASG without waiting for instances to be terminated. [This comment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/autoscaling/#DeleteAutoScalingGroupInput) on the AWS Go SDK docs explains it a little more:

```golang
    // Specifies that the group is to be deleted along with all instances associated
    // with the group, without waiting for all instances to be terminated. This
    // parameter also deletes any outstanding lifecycle actions associated with
    // the group.
    ForceDelete *bool `type:"boolean"`
```

Note that if you are relying on [autoscaling group lifecycle hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) (such as a [termination lifecycle hook that drains a container instance of any ECS tasks before the instance is terminated](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-automate-container-instance-draining-in-amazon-ecs/)) then these will be skipped.

If you are relying on termination lifecycle hooks then you can instead use a destroy time provisioner to shell out to the AWS CLI like you already tried but to remove the scale in protection using the [`aws autoscaling set-instance-protection` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/set-instance-protection.html):

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling_group" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = <<EOF
      AUTOSCALING_INSTANCE_IDS=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names ${self.name} --query 'AutoScalingGroups[0].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text)
      aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --auto-scaling-group-name ${self.name} --instance-ids "$${AUTOSCALING_INSTANCE_IDS}" --no-protected-from-scale-in
    EOF

  }
}
```

Comment: What I see from console output during terraform destroy, Terraform is first trying to destroy ECS cluster and it waits for 10 minutes then, it says: **Error: Error deleting ECS cluster: ClusterContainsContainerInstancesException: The Cluster cannot be deleted while Container Instances are active or draining.**  Terraform version details: Terraform v0.14.7
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.46.0

Comment: You would need to show more of your code to show that issue then but it looks like Terraform's destroy graph is incorrectly trying to delete the ECS cluster before the ASG which it is unable to do due to that error. You'd still need the `force_delete` or destroy time provisioner to remove any scale in protected instances (eg when using capacity providers) but your issue is now more about the order of Terraform destroying things.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting that into another question so this doesn't become a multiple question question and editing this to be specifically about deleting ASGs with scale in protection.

Comment: created a separate question[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117174/during-terraform-destroy-terraform-is-trying-to-destroy-the-ecs-cluster-before)